# How do I disable Steam Overlay in Blender?

Tags: interface

I have blender installed, but NOT part of my Steam library.
While both steam and blender are running, Shift+Tab or Shift+R somehow pulls up the steam overlay on top of blender, and I can't shut it off.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you run Blender from within another application which *is* run from Steam.

For example, if I'm developing a Unity game with Steam support, it loads the steam libraries and Steam thinks it is "running under Steam". Any sub-process also gets caught by this overzealous intercept.

I fix it by disabling the overlay just *for the app I'm developing.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to got blender in your library -> Right Click -> Properties -> General.  Then uncheck Enable the steam overlay while in-game.  However I tested my blender, which I'm using through steam, and it does not show the overlay when I press shift+tab or shift+r.  I even tried Full screen mode in Blender.

Comment: What if I don't have Blender in my library? I installed it separately and never knew before this that you can actually get it from Steam. haha.